# How can I use obfuscation js with Vue and Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, encryption, nuxt.js, obfuscation

I am trying to obfuscate the Nuxt project with [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator). Looking at their documentation it looks like we have to import their plugin in Webpack plugins. But they dont have the documentation for Vue or Nuxt way to do it. I also tried searching on google, but there aren't no relevant examples.

I also want to exclude `node_modules` from obfuscation.

Nuxt js documentation has something like

```js
import webpack from 'webpack'

export default {
  build: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        // global modules
        $: 'jquery',
        _: 'lodash'
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

And Obsufaction has

```js
var WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

// webpack plugins array
plugins: [
  new WebpackObfuscator ({
      rotateStringArray: true
  }, ['excluded_bundle_name.js'])
]
```

How can i use it with nuxt and also exclude the `node_modules` folders?

Comment: Does [this one](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator/issues/77#issuecomment-820887999) work for you?

Comment: @kissu I also followed the same github issue. Already used that code. But not sure if it is working. How do I know if its working? Where can i see the results?

Comment: You could probably inspect either the source code or the code shipped in your network tab.

Comment: @kissu I dont think it is working. Everything looks like the way before :(

Comment: Do you have a [repro]?

Comment: @kissu yes

var WebpackObfuscator = require("webpack-obfuscator");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240318/discussion-between-gitam-gadtaula-and-kissu).